# How to access elements of a gridview

Tags: asp.net

i have a asp buttonfield in a asp:gridview as follows

```
<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Select" HeaderText="View" ShowHeader="True" Text="View" />
```

How do I access this element and give it some functionality(meaning, when i click the button, I want it to do something and not stare at me !)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CommandName value allows you to trap the command you wish to execute when the button is clicked. This event is raised by the GridView and can be trapped in the RowCommand event.
A small snippet below:

```
  void MyGridView_RowCommand(Object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e )
  {
    if(e.CommandName=="Select")
    {
      DoSomething();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks man, the shit is, in visual studio the event-handler is auto-generated and it does not accept it as a valid event-handler if you manually type it out !